# What will happen if I cleared the container view of the fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Does the fragment in it receive onDetach, onDestroy method? Or do I need to remove fragment first and then clear the view?

Comment: what? i didnt understand it at all

Comment: I mean if a fragment is attached under a viewcontainer, if I call "viewContainer.removeAllViews()", what will happen in that fragment, will that fragment receive "onDetach", "onDestroy" method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter the order you do it as far I understand it. If you clear the view, the fragment's elements will be removed from the activity's view but you still need to remove it from the fragment manager.

For example, I am creating something like the following in my activity:

```
ViewGroup viewFragments = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_fragments);
viewFragments.removeAllViews();

View child = ViewGroup.inflate(mActivity, R.layout.child_edit_item, null);
viewFragments.addView(child);

Fragment f = new MyFragment();

FragmentManager mgr = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = mgr.beginTransaction();
if (mgr.findFragmentByTag(p.getKey()) != null) {
    trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f, p.getKey());
} else {
    trans.add(R.id.fragment_container, f, p.getKey());
}
trans.commit();
```